# Check For all index , in GAMS

Tags: gams-math

Let 'I' from 1 till 100 , be a set , and w(I), u(I) be a parameters , how can code this statement in GAMS :

if  for all I we have w(I)<0 and w(I)*u(I) =0 then  display ' converged'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Display$(smax(I,w(I))<0 and smax(I,w(I)*u(I))=0 and smin(I,w(I)*u(I))=0) 'Converged';
```

Comment: thanks a lot . do you know What is the best book or source for learning GAMS?

Comment: I think this is a good starting point: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_Tutorial.html